# Troubles with arrays c#

Tags: c#

I've been tasked with writing a c# program which is meant to do the following:

You input the target directory.
The program searches if the directory exists. If it doesn't, request new input. Otherwise carry on.

Program gets files of a certain type (it's meant to be .epl files, but for working this out I'm just using .txt files) and adds them to the FilePathsA[] array.
An Array List is made from FilePathsA.

If the count of the list is 0; get file. (there will only ever be 1 file of its type in said folder).
If the count of the list is 1; take the filepath string, create a text reader instance. Read the text of the file, append the text, send the text to a printer.

Close text reader instance. 
Delete the file that was just printed. 
Clear the array list.

Repeat the get file process until a new file is found, print/delete that, repeat the cycle. It's meant to stay active until the program is shut down.

Getting the initial file works fine; it prints then deletes the file from the folder. However my issue is with the recursion in perpetuating this cycle. 
Once a file is deleted, it'll continuously "search" but not actually follow through. Debugging seems to indicate that it's not getting the new file at all.

Not sure how to go about solving this, here is the code excerpt:
http://pastebin.com/RNn7QqXJ

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It's for a friend who wants bar code labels printed with his Zebra printer. Rather than having someone send the file every time, he'd rather this process be automatic. I figured it'd be a good learning exercise, but I've been stumped for a while.

Comment: You should narrow down your question to a specific section of your code, and make it very specific.  This is a bit too vague... What's the actual question here?

Comment: It would help if you provided your efforts so far and what exactly you're struggling with, so we can help, rather than asking people to do your task for you.

Comment: I think the guy just wants to repeat the process, but his program doesn't find new files.

Comment: You just provided a fairly large spec, and a body of code, then wrote "Not sure how to go about solving this".  It seems as if you're most of the way there.  What exactly are you having problems with? What isn't working, and what progress have you made debugging?  Or do you want us to examine your program top-to-bottom?

Comment: @thecoop The problem is when I want to repeat the cycle. 
The FilePathsA array doesn't empty, if it found oldfile.txt and assigned it to FilePathsA[0], after deleting the file from the folder, I'd like newfile.txt in the folder to overwrite what was assigned in FilePathsA[0].

I did try before with a for loop (assuming that each new file would be FilePathsA[n+1] but that only worked when I tested it with multiple files in the folder.

Comment: @Petar Correct, exactly what I want.
Sorry for the vagueness, I'm fairly new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should put

```
string[] filePathsA;
ArrayList filePaths;
```

outside your loop

and

```
filePathsA = Directory.GetFiles(@dir, "*.txt");
filePaths = new ArrayList(filePathsA);
```

inside your `do ... while` block in its beginning.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `List<string>` rather than `ArrayList`...?

Comment: @thecoop Yes, but it is his code. He is responsible for using generics:)

Comment: When doing such, the while clause errors as the arraylist FilePaths doesn't exist in that context.

Comment: @Nemekh, Just move the references outside the loop. Look at my edit

Comment: @Petar This worked, assuming the newfile.txt shares the same name as the oldfile.txt. If the names are different, it results in:
http://pastebin.com/QVDFaPK5

Comment: @Nemekh Could you paste your new code in pastebin? Are you sure the file is deleted?

Comment: The file is indeed deleted. If there is no file present, it'll perpetuate the "Searching for epl file" every few seconds. If there is a file, but it's not the same name as before, it terminates. That was the main issue.
http://pastebin.com/wSVZUqT6

Comment: Are you sure "c:\directory\New Text Document.txt" exists? Is it the new file?

Comment: It's the old file; it no longer exists. I gave the new file a different name.

Comment: @Nemekh Try to debug your code. It's really hard to debug something from distance like in my situation. When I look at the code I don't find a mistake...

Comment: Not sure why, but on recompiling the program worked as intended.
I also noticed another problem while debugging (sb was adding all file contents together in one large string; I had to have sb.remove(0, fileLength) to clear it.
Thanks a lot for your help Petar.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you:

```
while( !shutdown )
{
   foreach( string filename in Directory.GetFiles(@dir, "*.txt")
   {
      printTheFile( filename );
      File.Remove( filename );
      Thread.Sleep(3000); //if you need to sleep
   }
   Thread.Sleep(3000); //if you need to sleep
}
```

Or even better set up a `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` and handle file creations.

Comment: I hadn't considered such, mostly from lack of knowing you could. Seems much simpler/cleaner.